# facebook api access a page's photo album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

So really what i would like to do is access my page's photos albums to include them into my own website. So i can upload to facebook and have that viewable on my own site.

I using the php skd but fql would be better for this as i can easily get a JSON object back and i believe i wouldn't need to use the sdk as this is for user's informtaion not a pages details.

So does anybody have ideas on this?

url i'm trying to access the query:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20album%20Where%20aid=%27118818791532414%27&format=JSON

Page i am taking the photos from:
www.facebook.com/mayfieldathleticfc

Album i am using as an example:
http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.118818791532414.24873.118816378199322

I thought maybe i hadn't set the photos to public but after closer inspection i don't believe you can do this?

Anyway thoughts are welcome =)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a little more routing around i realised that it was my id's and owners details that was not correct: api.facebook.com/method/… i had this sorted it worked.

Answer (score 1):

That URL returns to you an informative error message:

```
    {"error_code":102,"error_msg":"Session key invalid or no longer valid",
    "request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"fql.query"},
    {"key":"query","value":"SELECT name FROM album Where aid='118818791532414'"},
    {"key":"format","value":"JSON"}]}
```

To call Facebook APIs, you have to pass in a session key - even to access 'public' things.  A good starting point for learning how to authenticate and get a session key is http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: cheers for the answer dude. I was under the impression that using the fql you didn't need to get an authenticated session key. The reason for using the fql over session key.
After a little more routing around i realised that it was my id's and owners details that was not correct:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,%20aid%20FROM%20album%20Where%20owner=%20%27118816378199322%27%20AND%20aid=%27118816378199322_24852%27&format=JSONOnce i had this sorted it worked. Which does mean sadly this question was a little pointless. So i hope maybe somebody can learn this.